# Is tum_ardrone available in ROS Indigo?

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone, ardrone, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in using tum_ardrone package in one of my projects. I currently have a Ubuntu 14.04 machine with ROS Indigo installed.

Since there isn't adequate information on tum_ardrone, I wanted to know whether it is available/compatible in ROS Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201254/is-tum_ardrone-available-in-ros-indigo?/) by [Anirudh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21414/anirudh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it works fine. Just use the indigo branch from tum_ardrone's repository on github

https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone/tree/indigo-devel

---

Originally posted by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) with karma: 61 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0